# Web Audio API - Possible to detune specific LR channel of Osc?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, synthesis

The oscillator nodes in the API seem to have stereo output. Is there a way to detune the frequency of the output in *only one* of the stereo channels to create a phase effect? Without having to create two oscillator nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Detuning the frequency, no - but if you wanted something like a stereo phaser effect, you could pipe one channel (via a ChannelSplitterNode and ChannelMergerNode) through a DelayNode, and vary the delay (by piping a low-frequency Oscillator into the DelayNode's .delayTime).  But there's no individual frequency control for the output channels of the Oscillator; they're identical.

Comment: Oscillators have mono outputs.  Hmm. Can't find where in the spec it says that.  If you're getting stereo, you've upmixed it to stereo by sending the output to some other node that does upmixing, like a PannerNode.